# Using dependecy injection without setter is bad or good practise?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

What if my class has only private fields which injected by the container? Is it good or bad? In that case, I have to use DI framework in testing (and maybe that's not bad) but on the other hand, no setters, no unnecessary code. Is that bad practice or not?

Comment: Typically I'd use a constructor instead of letting the container set the fields directly... using a constructor makes it easy to test, and allows the fields to be final with no whinging from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Setter methods are way of achieving abstraction which is one the most important principle of OOP. Ideally the code should not be dependent on container. I think setter methods will provide standard way of using DI and in addition good code readability. I always consider setter DI a good practice unless my class instantiation is dependent on some other dependency (for which i will use constructor based DI).

I think you should not depend on container for performing DI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**First, what are the alternatives to DI via setter methods? Martin Fowler distinguishes [three ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Types): **interface, setter and constructor injection**. So none of these ways is good or bad by definition, it's how you use them and what suits your system best. If you want your fields immutable during after object creation, use constructor injection with private fields.
Nonetheless Setter injection is the most common way of DI and several frameworks rely on it. If you're unsure go with this way. You'll also find lots of information about it.

If your question targets the use of setters at all, the question is **if your class is a data structure** (see Martin's [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1377765796&sr=1-1&keywords=clean%20code) ch. 6 for detailed information). In other words, if your class has no other purpose than holding some data and you can make your fields public(*). If it holds business logic, use private fields and getters/setters.

(*) personally I disagree with that, but that's only me. :-)